# Jenkins EnvInject from a file which is a Job parameter by itself

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've got a Job Parameter, for example PROPERTIES_FILE.

I want to inject all Env Variables from that file into my job session, using the EnvInject plugin.

Is there a way to do that?

I managed to inject variables
 only for a hard coded file path, and not from a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

[EnvFile plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Envfile+Plugin) (not EnvInject) seems to support variables in the properties file path (as it uses $WORKSPACE in the example).

Also, if you are on Windows, maybe all you need for EnvInject plugin to work is to use `$param` for variable, not `%param%`. While the scripts need `%%` notation, inside Jenkins still uses `$`